# I just started codeing and i need some help reagarding my assignment in javascript

Tags: javascript

When left-clicking anywhere on the page, "B" should change to "click"

```
function change_text(){
var p2 = document.getElementById("p2").value;
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "click";
}
```

Comment: you want a click handler, probably on `document` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Comment: Welcome to JS! I hope you understand the answer now (the one below is pretty correct). I'd recommend googling these questions before posting on StackOverflow, just because it's much easier and convenient for everyone. I'd like to ask: Which course gave you this assignment? It seems to be outdated, judging by the use of `var` instead of `let`/`const`. Sorry if I come across as rude, I had a rough time self-learning JS so I'd like to guide people new to JS in the right direction

Comment: What is "B"? Did you mean `p2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in HTML

```
<body onload="change_text()">
```

In your JS file

```
function change_text(){
  const p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
  document.addEventListener('click', function () {
    p2.innerHTML = 'click'
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Listener 'mouseup' (after click) or 'mousedown' (as soon as the button is pressed)

The capture and passive down there will make more faster, it's a garantee that you will not stop normal click events in your function.

```
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (){
        document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "click";
    }, {
        capture: true,
        passive: true
    })
```